# How to perform a side effect after another side effect rendered a react component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have the following simple use case:
The component `ServerRendered` is used to render markup that is retrieved from a server using the property `url` . In `ServerRendered` I use useEffect to load the markup from the back-end, set the state to the current markup and render it in a div.
The property `init` optionally specifies a function that should be executed after having rendered the markup.
How would I run the init function after the markup has been rendered?

```js
/* eslint-disable react/no-danger */

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

type ServerRenderedPropsType = {
    url: string,
    init?: () => void,
};

function ServerRendered(props: ServerRenderedPropsType) {
    const [html, setHtml] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const result = await axios(props.url);
            setHtml(result.data.title);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [props.url]);

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} className="serverRendered" />;
}

export default ServerRendered;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just to do another effet when you receive your data

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

type ServerRenderedPropsType = {
    url: string,
    init?: () => void,
};

function ServerRendered(props: ServerRenderedPropsType) {
    const [html, setHtml] = useState('');
    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        const result = await axios(props.url);
        setHtml(result.data.title);
      }, [props.url])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);

    useEffect(() => {
      // do what you want here
      if (!html) return;
      props.init()
    }, [html])

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} className="serverRendered" />;
}

export default ServerRendered;
```

Comment: I understand, but would the second effect not also be fired before the markup was already rendered?

Comment: no it will rendered at the same time when the `html` is updated, but you can add in your effet `if (!html) return`

Comment: I just double checked in my sample app and the second use effect will be invoked twice: the first time before the markup has been rendered (html==='') and then again after rendering.